# pandas groupby nunique per multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,2,3], 
                   'user':['u1', 'u1', 'u2', 'u2', 'u3'],
                   'date':['2021-04-25','2021-04-25','2021-04-25','2021-04-26', '2021-04-25'],
                   'sth_else1':['xx','yy','xx','xx','xx'], 'sth_else2':['zz','yy','zz','xx','xx']})
```

```
   id   user    date    sth_else1   sth_else2
0   1   u1  2021-04-25  xx          zz
1   1   u1  2021-04-25  yy          yy
2   2   u2  2021-04-25  xx          zz
3   2   u2  2021-04-26  xx          xx
4   3   u3  2021-04-25  xx          xx
```

and I would like to add a column (so probably use groupby with transform?) to that dataframe that shows me the number of unique user/date combinations I have per id in the whole dataframe, so that I would get this

```
   id   user    date    sth_else1   sth_else2   count_per_id_user_and_date
0   1   u1  2021-04-25  xx          zz          1
1   1   u1  2021-04-25  yy          yy          1
2   2   u2  2021-04-25  xx          zz          2
3   2   u2  2021-04-26  xx          xx          2
4   3   u3  2021-04-25  xx          xx          1
```

how would I do this?

Comment: `df['count_per_id_user_and_date'] = df.groupby(['id', 'user', 'date'])['date'].transform('size')`, not sure why you mentioned `nunique` in the title. Note that counting the unique items in sth_else2 gives the same result (`df.groupby(['id', 'user', 'date'])['sth_else2'].transform('nunique')`)

Comment: I made it the example clearer: I would like to have the number of unique date/user combinations per id. So id 2 has two different user/date combinations while id 1 and 3 only have one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count the number of unique combinations of user/date per id, you can first identify the non-duplicates, then [`groupby.transform('sum')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['count_per_id_user_and_date'] = (~df[['id', 'user', 'date']].duplicated()
                                   ).groupby(df['id']).transform('sum')
```

Or:

```
df['count_per_id_user_and_date'] = df['id'].map(
    df[['id', 'user', 'date']].drop_duplicates()
    .groupby('id').size()
)
```

Output:

```
   id user        date sth_else1 sth_else2  count_per_id_user_and_date
0   1   u1  2021-04-25        xx        zz                           1
1   1   u1  2021-04-25        yy        yy                           1
2   2   u2  2021-04-25        xx        zz                           2
3   2   u2  2021-04-26        xx        xx                           2
4   3   u3  2021-04-25        xx        xx                           1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this piece of code to make it happen

```py
df['final_result'] = df.groupby(['id', 'user', 'date'])['id'].transform('size')
```

Comment: I would like to have the number of unique user/date combinations per id, this gives me the the total count